# Power Query - count of all rows where cell starts with text of current row's cell

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am trying create the equivalent of an Excel formula in Excel's Power Query editor. I have an Excel file with a bunch of rows, and a column containing the URL path of the file/folder in a normal Windows structure. I am trying to use this to count up all rows/files/folders which are "this folder", or deeper files/subfolders.

the current Excel formula is:

```
=COUNTIF(A$2:A$238602,A2&"*")
```

The idea is to get the path-value of the current row (*A2*), and check all the other rows (*A$2:A$238602*) to see if the those rows start with (*A2&"*"*) the same text, and then count up all those rows where it does (*COUNTIF*).The data looks a bit like this:

X:\Admin\
X:\Admin\Records\
X:\Admin\Records\Delegated 2019\
X:\Admin\Records\Delegated 2019\Management.xlsx
X:\Admin\Records\Delegated 2019\Business.xls
X:\Admin\Records\Monitoring_2019.xlsx
X:\Admin\Records\Progression 2018.docx
X:\Admin\Leader Meetings\
X:\Admin\Leader Meetings\Leader Meeting 10 May 2016.docx
X:\Admin\Leader Meetings\Cross Team Group.docx
X:\Admin\Templates\
X:\Admin\Templates\Business Card Template.pdf
X:\Admin\Templates\Excel\
X:\Admin\Templates\Excel\PivotTable for SubProjects.docx
X:\Apprentice\
X:\Apprentice\Meetings\

so, the result for "X:\Admin\" is 14, "X:\Admin\Records\" is 6, "X:\Admin\Leader Meetings\" is 3, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count the number of elements in the path column that start with the current path like this:

```
= Table.AddColumn(Source, "Count",
    (row) => List.Count(List.Select(Source[Path], each Text.StartsWith(_, row[Path]))),
  Int64.Type)
```

This takes the entire column (list) `Source[Path]` and selects only the elements that satisfy the condition that it starts with the current row's path value and then counts how many elements are in that filtered list.

[image: Result]